# Integer solutions of a less than inequality

Tags: combinatorics

I need to determine how many integer solutions are to this inequality:$$ y_1 +y_2 +y_3 < 100 $$

with $$y_1 > 0,y_2 ∈ [0,10],y_3 ∈ (0,19]$$

I'm having trouble where to start. I know that$$y_1+y_2+y_3=99 $$since $100 $ is not possible to reach. Then I get stuck upon what I should do next.

Comment: The sum can be any integer in $[2, 99]$.

Answer (score 4):

For any given values of $y_2$ and $y_3$, there are $99 - y_2 - y_3$ values of $y_1$ that work.

Therefore, the answer is 
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^{10} \sum_{j=1}^{19} 99 - i - j
$$

Which you can calculate using the formula $1+2+ \dots n = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be to let $y_4=99-(y_1+y_2+y_3)$, $\;\;$so $\;\;y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=99$.

Now let $t_1=y_1-1, \;\;t_2=y_2, \;\;t_3=y_3-1, \;\;t_4=y_4\;\;$ so that $t_i\ge0$ for each i.

Then you want to find the number of integer solutions to

$\;\;\;\;t_1+t_2+t_3+t_4=97\;\;$ 
where $\;\;t_1\ge0, \;\;0\le t_2\le10,\;\; 0\le t_3\le18, \;\;t_4\ge0$,

which gives $\displaystyle\binom{100}{3}-\binom{89}{3}-\binom{81}{3}+\binom{70}{3}=17,556$.

Comment: Could you explain the values of t1, t2, t3, and t4 of why did you do that (like the reasoning behind it)?

Comment: Sure, I will edit my answer to try to explain this.

Comment: I thought that y1+y2+y3+y4=100 since a restriction of y4 is including 0 to infinity?

Comment: We wanted $y_1+y_2+y_3\le99$, so we can let $y_4=99-(y_1+y_2+y_3)$.

Comment: That kind of makes sense. I thought that adding an extra variable gives the inequality a placeholder. Also, could you explain the way you figured out the combinations for the solution? My book doesn't explain it very well.

Comment: @Miriam: The extra variable takes up the slack between the sum of the three ‘real’ ones and the maximum possible sum of $99$. For the other part, take a look at my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251067/colored-blocks-factorial) and the one linked from that answer, and see if they help.

Comment: why is it C(81,3)?

Comment: I did y3>=20 and got C(80,3).