# Homework - How many non negative solutions?

Tags: combinatorics

$a+b+c+d+e = 30$

we know that $10\leq e$ and that $4\leq d \leq 7$

How many non negative solutions does this equation have?

Comment: Infinitely many.

Comment: Sorry the question was not clear. I meant integer non negative solutions

Comment: You can set this question up as a combinatorial problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a'=a$, $b\,'=b$, $c'=c$, $d\,'=d-4$, and $e'=e-10$; $30-(4+10)=16$, so you’re trying to count solutions in non-negative integers to

$$a'+b\,'+c'+d\,'+e'=16\tag{1}$$

with the extra condition that $d\,'\le 3$. Without the extra conditions this is just a [stars-and-bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29); $(1)$ has

$$\binom{16+5-1}{5-1}=\binom{20}4$$

unrestricted solutions in non-negative integers. (Both the formula and a decent derivation of it can be found at the link.) Of course some of these violate the upper bounds on the variables and have to be subtracted from this count. That’s a basic [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) problem; my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203835/enumerating-number-of-solutions-to-an-equation) illustrates the method in a similar but slightly more difficult problem.

Comment: @Calvin: Thanks for catching that; fixed now.

Comment: @Calvin: Argh! For some reason I was thinking that it was only the upper bound that was affected. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

That would be the coefficient of $x^{30}$ in 
$$P(x)=(1+x+x^2+...)^3(x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)(x^{10}+x^{11}+x^{12}+...)$$

Noting we can write $P(x)$ as$\dfrac{x^{14}}{(1-x)^4}(1+x+x^2+x^3) $, we need the sum of coefficients of $x^{13}, x^{14}, x^{15}, x^{16}$ in  $\dfrac1{(1-x)^4}$.  Use the Binomial Theorem for finding these coefficients.