# Number of ways to distribute $N$ coins among $M$ people, when each person can only have a maximum of $C$ coins?

Tags: permutations, combinations

A person can however receive $0$ coins.
Example - Number of ways of distributing $3$ coins among $2$ people such that no person receive more than $2$ coins is $2$.

My approach -
For a simpler version if we do not have restriction of each person having a maximum of C coins.

We know that $$ \sum coins(\{ (c_1,...,c_M) \}) = N $$

Then Number of ways to distribute N coins among M people will be $$ {{N+M -1}\choose{M-1}} $$

I fail to understand how to include restriction of each person having having a maximum of C coins.

Comment: Are you assuming that the coins are distinct or indistinguishable?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Include that in question.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig All coins are identical.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203835/enumerating-number-of-solutions-to-an-equation this post might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is incorrect, as I noted in a comment.  There isn't a very compact formula for this, so far as I know.  You can do it with generating functions.  I'll use the coefficient extractor operator.  $[x^n]P(x)$ mean the coefficient of $x^n$ in the polynomial or power series $P(x)$.

The number of ways to distribute $N$ coins to $M$ people, with a limit of $C$ coins per person is
$$\begin{align}
&[x^N](1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^C)^M\\
=&[x^N]\left(\frac{1-x^{C+1}}{1-x}\right)^M\\
=&[x^N]\sum_{k=0}^M(-1)^k\binom Mkx^{k(C+1)}(1-x)^{-M}\\
=&[x^N]\sum_{k=0}^M(-1)^k\binom Mkx^{k(C+1)}\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^j\binom{-M}{j}x^j\\
=&[x^N]\sum_{k=0}^M(-1)^k\binom Mkx^{k(C+1)}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{M+j-1}{j}x^j\\
=&\sum_{k=0}^M(-1)^k\binom Mk\binom{M+N-k(C+1)-1}{N-k(C+1)} 
\end{align},$$ with the usual convention that $\binom nm = 0$ if $m<0$ so that we can take $$0\leq k\leq\left\lfloor\frac{N}{C+1}\right\rfloor$$ and the sum becomes
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor N/(C+1)\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom Mk\binom{M+N-k(C+1)-1}{M-1}$$

The first formula comes by considering the exponent of $x$ in the $j$th term as the number of coins given to person $j$.  Then the coefficient of $x^N$ in the product counts the number of ways that we actually distributed $N$ coins.  The remainder comes from the binomial theorem and binomial formula.  In the very last line, we pick out the value $j$ that results in an exponent of $N$.

**EXAMPLE**

With $M=N=3,\ C=2$, the above formula gives $$\sum_{k=0}^1(-1)^k\binom3k\binom{5-3k}{3-3k}=\binom30\binom53-\binom31\binom20=7$$ which is correct.  The accepted answer gives $10$.

**EDIT**

This is the same formula one would get by applying the principle of inclusion and exclusion.  The first term in the sum, $\binom{N+M-1}{M-1}$ is the number of ways to distribute $N$ coins to $M$ people without restriction.  In the second term, we subtract $\binom M1\binom{N-(C+1)+M-1}{M-1}$, the number of ways to give one person $C+1$ coins, and then distribute the remaining $N-(C+1)$ coins.  Any distributions where two people got more than $C$ coins have been subtracted twice, so we add back the third term, $\binom M2\binom{N-2(C+1)+M-1}{M-1}$, the number of ways to give two people $C+1$ coins each, and then distribute the remaining $N-2(C+1)$ coins, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is actually incorrect, but I will leave it here in case anyone makes the same mistake I did in reasoning this out. Take a look at saulspatz's response for the right answer :)

---

I am assuming that $N<MC$, otherwise there are zero ways.

The idea is the following: first give each person $C$ coins, and then take away $MC-N$ coins by choosing from the $M$ people with repetition allowed and order not important.

This corresponds to the number $\big(\!\!\binom{M}{MC-N}\!\!\big) = \binom{M+MC-N-1}{MC-N}$, where $\big(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\big)$ denotes [multichoose](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multichoose.html).

Comment: If $MC-N>C$ doesn't this count cases where you take away more than one coin from a single person?

Comment: For example, if $M=N=3,\ C=2$ the above gives $10$, but there are $7$ ways to distribute $3$ coins among $3$ people witha limit of $2$ coins per person.  Give each person $1$ coin, or give one person $2$ and another $1$.

Comment: @saulspatz You're right, I overlooked this. Thank you for pointing it out.