# Number of integer solutions such that each number is less than 7

Tags: combinatorics

Find the integer solutions to
$$x_1 + \dots x_{10} = 25$$ such that $$1 \leq x_i \leq 6$$

I made transformation $$y_i = 7 - x_i$$ and got the new problem as $$y_1 + \dots + y_{10} = 45$$ but in this case I can have $$y_i = 8$$ which would mean that $$x_i = -1$$. How do I solve this then?

Edit: any other solution is appreciated.

Comment: Well, one way of obtaining the number of solutions, would be to calculate the coefficient of $x^{25}$ in
$$
(x^1+x^2 + x^3 + x^4  + x^5+ x^6)^{10}
$$

Comment: I don’t understand how this solution works.

Comment: Do you need to find **the solutions** or **the number of solutions**? To me, it looks like a pretty standard combinatorics question that asks to find the number of solutions.

Comment: @MattiP. Number of solutions

Comment: Notice also this similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203835/enumerating-number-of-solutions-to-an-equation

Comment: Did you mean nonnegative integer solutions or positive integer solutions?  In either case, you can apply the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  First, find the number of solutions without restriction, then eliminate those cases in which or more of the variables assumes a value greater than $6$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes i think I’ve got it now, thanks a lot.